# Firestore Timestamp variable throws TypeError: startDate.toMillis is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two Timestamps in a cloud function.

```
const diff = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toMillis() - licence.startDate.toMillis();
```

My Licence Type contains the field startDate of the type Timestamp which is set before.
The `admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toMillis()` does not throw this exception.

Environment Information:

```
Operating System version: Windows 10 Home 10.0.18363 Build 18363
Firebase SDK version: 8.2.3
Node Version: 14
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

The type definition of the Licence Type

```
export type Licence = {
    type: LicenceType;
    creationDate: Timestamp;
    startDate?: Timestamp | null;
    validityPeriod: number; // In Days
    ownerId: string;
    userVolume: number;
    assistantVolume: number;
    activatedUser: number;
    activatedAssistant: number;
}
```

Comment: the issue has to do with the `licence.startDate` definition, so could you share the class license?

Comment: I used a Type and not a class and Timestamp is a firestore specific class or type(not sure)

The Timestamp type has seconds field and is use this instead and it worked

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, I think because I was passing in a firebase.firestore.Timestamp and comparing it to a admin.firestore.Timestamp using toMillis(). The workaround I came up with, as per your code above would be:

const diff = (admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds - licence.startDate.seconds)*1000;